# Multiple Histograms in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe df with below attributes

```
ID                  X1                       X2
0                  3969518                   24700
1                  8111123                   20000
2                  250000                    987000
3                  10745929                  5000
```

I m trying to plot a multiple histogram like this

[image]

I am using seaborn and matplotlib

```
x1 = df2[['X1']]
x2 = df2[['X2']]
kwargs = dict(histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3, normed=True, bins=20)
plt.hist(x1, **kwargs)
plt.hist(x2, **kwargs);
```

but i get the below error

```
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: The code you show works fine and does not produce any error. It produces [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gxpb.png).

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix, you need to consider the array not the pandas series:

```
x1 = df2[['X1']]
x2 = df2[['X2']]
kwargs = dict(histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3, normed=True, bins=20)
plt.hist(x1.values, **kwargs)
plt.hist(x2.values, **kwargs);
```

Alternatively:

```
x1 = df2[['X1']]
x2 = df2[['X2']]
kwargs = dict(histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3, normed=True, bins=20)
plt.hist(data=x1, x='X1', **kwargs)
plt.hist(data=x2, x='X2', **kwargs);
```

Or even better you don't need to define two new series:

```
kwargs = dict(histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3, normed=True, bins=20)
plt.hist(data=df2, x='X1', **kwargs)
plt.hist(data=df2, x='X2', **kwargs);
```

Comment: I guess those are all valid alternatives, but the code from the question works fine as well, so I don't think this is useful.

Comment: Might depend on the version, it gives me the same error